# Laravel optionnal parameters in routes

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5

I want to have this two url working with one route:

> mysite.com/search

and

> mysite.com/food/search

I have done this but this is working only with the second one.

```
Route::group([ 'prefix' => '{section?}' ], function(){
    Route::get('/search', [ 'as' => 'search', 'uses' => 'PostController@search' ]);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Why you don't  use 
**mysite.com/search/food** 
instead  of
mysite.com/food/search ?

By doing that , You will have now multiple solution for your routes **one of these** :

```
Route::group( [ 'prefix' => 'search' ], function() {
     //your code

     //as an example 
     Route::get('/',....);
     Route::get('/food' , ... ) ;
});
```

This will make your url more Human reading and easy to add features to it .

Answer (score 1):

I dont believe in this situation it is necessary to block it into a group. There are several approaches for wildcard routing in laravel.

Using a slug:

```
Route::get('{section?}/search', [ 'as' => 'search', 'PostController@search']);
```

Using a wildcard:

```
Route::get('(:any?)/search', ['as' => 'search', 'PostController@search']);
```

Using Regular Expressions:

```
Route::get('(.*)/search', ['as' => 'search', 'PostController@search']);
```

Obviously if you want to do handling of the wildcard you will need to pass a parameter into your search method in the PostController.

I haven't used Laravel in a while so this may be fuzzy but I think this should solve your problem.